# RSA encryption in C++. Having an issue with reverting modulus operation

Tags: c++, rsa, modulus

I'm trying to create a simple RSA encryption/decryption program in C++, which deal only with integers as the encrypted "text."

My "encrypt" method looks like this:

```
long int encryptedText = (long)fmod(pow(toBeEncrypted, pubE), pubN);
```

With a sample input of 15 for toBeEncrypted, 5 for pubE, and 2117 for pubN, it outputs me 1489, which is mathematically correct.

The issue is when I try to decrypt, my output is not correct. I reverse the modulus like so:
`decryptedText = fmod(pow(fmod(toBeDecrypted, pubN), pubD), pubN);`

When I have 1489 for toBeDecrypted, 1613 for pubD, and 2117 for pubN, I get an output of -9223372036854775808 with no other errors.

I assume my issue is that the storage overflows, but I'm not sure how to handle it as I'm already using long ints to keep my values.

Thanks for any help or insight

**UPDATE**

I've divided my decryption modulus to many smaller modulus operation, but have the same negative output

```
for (int i=0; i < pubD, i++;){
    decryptedText *= fmod(pow(toBeDecrypted, 1), pubN);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you write your own function to calculate `a^b mod c`, so that you prevent the huge intermediate value of `a^b`.

Comment: `fmod` & `pow` - There's your problem floating point does not have enough precision.  RSA is done with multi-precision integer arithmetic. And uses the relationship `(a*b)%m == ((a%m) * (b%m))%m` as the basic building block to implement raising a number to a power and taking the modulus.

Comment: @RichardCritten what would be the best way for me to implement this then? Do I just take the modulus more frequently? ie; between exponents?

Comment: Have a look at modular exponentiation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: I've tried to divide it like so: `for (int i=0; i < pubD, i++;){
 decryptedText *= fmod(pow(toBeDecrypted, 1), pubN);
}`and still have the enormous negative output.

Comment: Try removing all floating point library calls (they are not helping you) and using only integers. Now step through your code checking for overflow,
 asserts will also work - test if the new number is less than the old number - then you have wrapped (not a perfect test but good enough).